# Using SDL2 with g++ / MinGW crashes on launch

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, sdl-2, mingw-w64

I am working on a game and recently made the transition from SDL 1.2 to SDL2 (kinda late to the party but heh). Despite having no compilation or linking error whatsoever, the program crashed on launch while stating (translated from French) "The application failed to start up correctly". At first I thought it was my own fault, but then I got suspicious and put together a quick SDL2 test, which indeed after flawless compilation crashed on launch.

Here is the code I've been using for this example (you can't make it more simple) :

```
#include <SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

And the compilation line is `g++ main.cpp -ISDL2-2.0.4\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 -LSDL2-2.0.4\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -otest.exe -fpermissive -std=c++11 -Wno-write-strings -Wno-overflow`

For what it's worth :

```
> g++ --version
g++ (x86_64-win32-seh, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 6.1.0
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I'm running MinGW-w64 on Windows, as you can see. The OS is Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Welp. I actually used the wrong SDL2.dll. I feel dumb now.

Comment: Ahh, dammit, thanks for adding the follow-up -- this was exactly what I also did, and instantly forgot, so this reminder spared me some long, futile googling. :)